# How can I lock inserting in multiple table?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, locking

I used this command to insert multiple records in multiple rows, how can I lock my command and rollback changes if insertion was unsuccessfull?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string s = @"

                declare @one_id int; 

                INSERT INTO tbl_one(o1,o2,o3) VALUES(@o1,@o2,@o3);

                set @one_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                INSERT INTO tbl_two(t1,t2,f3) VALUES(@t1,@t2,@one_id);
                INSERT INTO tbl_two(t1,t2,f3) VALUES(@t3,@t4,@one_id);
                INSERT INTO tbl_two(t1,t2,f3) VALUES(@t5,@t6,@one_id);
                ";

        cmd.CommandText =s;
```

Comment: Use transaction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you familiar with try catch statements , so use it.

Wrap your statements in a BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT, like this:

```
        string s = @"
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION 
                declare @one_id int; 

                INSERT INTO tbl_one(o1,o2,o3) VALUES(@o1,@o2,@o3);

                set @one_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                INSERT INTO tbl_two(t1,t2,f3) VALUES(@t1,@t2,@one_id);
                INSERT INTO tbl_two(t1,t2,f3) VALUES(@t3,@t4,@one_id);
                INSERT INTO tbl_two(t1,t2,f3) VALUES(@t5,@t6,@one_id);
            COMMIT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK
        END CATCH
        ";
```

If one of your statements will fail, CATCH block will start.

good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but can you describe something  about @@TRANCOUNT?

Comment: @@TRANCOUNT -> "Returns the number of BEGIN TRANSACTION statements that have occurred on the current connection" see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can start the transaction and manage errors in SQL code as Roy suggests, or you can do it at client side:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = CreateConnection())
using (SqlCommand cmd = CreateMyCommand(cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction tx = cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cmd.Transaction = tx;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        tx.Commit();
    }       
}
```

Note that a catch block is not needed here because if something fails the transaction is rolled back on tx.Dispose(). If something fails, tx.commit is not called but tx.Dispose is always called because of the using block. Tx.Dispose rollbacks the transaction if it has not been previously committed.

Comment: Which on is better ? client side or SQL server side? Does it prevent concurrency problems in this scenario ?

Comment: Nothing prevents concurrency problems. Optimistic concurrency strategy, isolation levels and transactions help to deal with they but the problems don't go away magically.

Comment: IMHO none of them is better than the other one. I think it's a matter of preference, their behaviour are almost the same but subtle different.

Answer (score 1):

Below links would be help you :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522039/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-Transaction
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx